# Magento: payment transaction in PDF (how to)

Tags: magento, pdf, transactions, payment

In admin/sales_order/view I can print the order.
Now I want to add the transaction ID to the pdf.
But how to do this? I know it should be somewhere in app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help..

```
$orderData = $order->getPayment()->getData();
$additional = $orderData['additional_information']['authorize_cards'];
$keys = array_keys($additional);
$transactionId = $additional[$keys[0]]['last_trans_id'];
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks. But that leaves the question where to put it...?

Comment: check which function is called when you print the PDF. You may need to rewrite that function in order to include this feature.